# How detailed and specific unit tests should be?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I know the title may seem slightly vague, so let me clarify it - the question is about some the reasonable amount and depth of unit tests. I'm reading a book that suggests testing API CRUD operations this way:

https://bitbucket.org/paulredmond/bookr/src/74cb5faa3254c1182ebcf75254b1a7d3ce775691/tests/app/Http/Controllers/BooksControllerValidationTest.php#lines-58

(line 58 to the end of the file).

Is that a viable and sustainable approach in real projects to create tests for every single validation criteria of every single entity (actually, 4 validation tests per entity field) ?

Comment: Everyone will have a slightly different opinion on this. There is not 1 right answer. In my opinion the test you linked is very valid. It tests a crucial part of the code that even has its own error message. Now you can debate when a test goes too far. For example: Do you also want to test if it throws this error when you use 256 whitespaces? Does it also throw it when you put only numbers in? Does it throw the error when you use special characters? In my opinion that would be over testing the code, but it does make your tests cover more scenario's. So not 1 right answer in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks @DirkScholten, I expected this answer, I know it depends. But what are the factors here? I mean if anyone can share their real world project experience that would help better understand these factors.

Comment: In my experience the deciding factor would be that there is a line of code that validates the title length. So if you have a line of code that checks the title length, write a test for it. Do you have a validation check that no special characters can be used? Write a check for that. But don't write a test for every special character you can think of. Hope that makes sense.